# Quick colour change from 1 to another

Tags: colors, hex

I'm updating a site for a client with new branding colours,  Is there a code I could change that would allow me to change all the colours with a certain code to another colour code without having to go through it all that can be used on the custom style sheet?

Comment: Pretty much all text editors have a search and replace function, usually mapped to Ctrl + H on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use the "replace in files" option of my editor for such problems.